# I want to make a python script that subtracts latest value with the previous value and saves the result in a new column in a new text file

Tags: python

I have a column for some data points ranging from 1 to 19999 in a text file, I want to subtract each of the new value with the previous value and save the answer in a new column in a new text file.

My data points (in a column) with index number in a text file looks like:

```
1 66.295962
2 66.318076
3 66.479436
4 66.460284
5 66.551778
6 66.303606
7 66.222943
8 66.50905
9 66.268011
10 66.291807
.    .
.    .
.    .
.    .
19993 69.303592
19994 69.384204
19995 69.375126
19996 69.417533
19997 69.296388
19998 69.284336
19999 69.403861
```

How to make program for this in python, any help would be really appreciated.. Thanks in advance, I have already tried to convert my column in to the list but I cannot figure it out how to subtract values and save the answer in a new column of a new  text file....

My program looks like this:

```
f = open ('infilename', 'r')
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    columns = line.split()
   # for i in xrange(len(columns)):
    print columns[1]

import csv

#open file
infile = open('infilename', 'r')

#define csv reader object, assuming delimiter is tab
tsvfile = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t')

lines = []

## iterate through lines in file
for line in tsvfile:
    lines.append(line)

print "Col1",[line[0] for line in lines]
```

Comment: What you mean by `new value` and `previous value` did you mean for example row 1,2 and 2,3 or 1,2 and 3,4 and so on ?

Comment: I mean I want to subtract value at index 19999 with the value at index 19998 and so on up to 1st index , and want to save the values in a column in to new text file.

subtracting should be in a relationship :

n= (n) - (n-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a noob, might I suggest using Python and NumPy for handling and processing data in tabular form.  Most installations come with NumPy (or Pandas) so it is a worthwhile tool in the toolkit.  Forgive the formatting, I am not used to this site

Here is the file sample (I can't get formatted so it is on separate lines):

```
1 66.295962   
2 66.318076
3 66.479436
4 66.460284
5 66.551778
6 66.303606
7 66.222943
8 66.50905
9 66.268011
10 66.291807
```

Do some imports,

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rfn
```

Load the text file as an array with a set data type (dtype).

```
>>> f = np.loadtxt("f:/test/test.txt",dtype=[('ID','int32'),('Value','float64')])
>>> f
array([(1, 66.295962), (2, 66.318076), (3, 66.479436), (4, 66.460284),
       (5, 66.551778), (6, 66.303606), (7, 66.222943), (8, 66.50905),
       (9, 66.268011), (10, 66.291807)], 
      dtype=[('ID', '<i4'), ('Value', '<f8')])
```

Create a second column of data shifted/rolled by one entry, to facilitate subtraction

```
>>> a = f['Value']
>>> a1 = np.roll(a,-1)
>>> diff = a1-a
```

Create the output text file by merging the original array and the difference
array (with some mumbo-jumbo describing how)

```
>>> out = rfn.merge_arrays((f, diff), asrecarray=True, flatten=True)
```

Finally create the output table and save as a text file trying to retain some
semblence of formatting.

```
>>> np.savetxt("f:/test/out.txt", out, delimiter="",fmt='% 10i % 10.6f % 10.6f')
```

Resulting in the following (you can put headers etc etc.)

```
     1  66.295962   0.022114
     2  66.318076   0.161360
     3  66.479436  -0.019152
     4  66.460284   0.091494
     5  66.551778  -0.248172
     6  66.303606  -0.080663
     7  66.222943   0.286107
     8  66.509050  -0.241039
     9  66.268011   0.023796
    10  66.291807   0.004155
```

Note...the last entry in the 3rd column is the difference between the last and the first values in the 2nd column.  The pairing between where the differences lie and the original values depend whether you rolled forward or you rolled backwards.  In the example presented, I rolled backwards, so the first difference is between the first and second value in column 2.  This can be adjusted to suit your purposes and the final/first value can be set to 0, depending upon whether you roll forward or backwards.

Comment: but how can I make an array from the text file or large data set saved in text file, e,g I have 19999 data sets for this data saved in a text file ... mean to say how numpyarray can take input automatically ??

Comment: your program seems really simple and easy to me,I am really thankful to you. but let me know how to input data points for 19999 indices in to the array?

Comment: The example was from a text file, as shown in the example line... f = np.loadtxt("f:/test/test.txt", ... it was text.txt

Answer (score 1):

i have come up with this:

```
input_list = [(i, float(num.split()[1])) for i, num in enumerate(f.read().splitlines())]
output_list = [input_list[i[0]][1] - input_list[i[0]-1][1] for i in input_list if i[0] != 0]
```

gets me this:

```
0.022114
0.16136
-0.019152
0.091494
-0.248172
-0.080663
0.286107
-0.241039
0.023796
```

Comment: other values are correct except the first value as our program is subtracting the 10th index from 1st one.... approach should be n = (n) - (n-1) where n is the index number...

Comment: Added an `if` to the last list comprehension. Is that more like you need it?

Comment: @LifeSciences This is not a correct way for solving this problem. it used a lot of indexing an also for long lists its pretty inefficient at memory efficiency and speed efficiency perspective!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CSV` module for reading your file and then use `itertools.izip` to access the expected pairs then write to output :

```
import csv
from itertools import izip_longest
from operator import sub
with open('new.txt', 'r') as csvfile,open('out.txt','w') as out:
     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
     z=izip_longest(*spamreader)
     next(z)
     z=next(z)
     try :
        for i,j in izip_longest(z,z[1:]):
           out.write(str(sub(float(j),float(i)))+'\n')
     except:
        pass
```

Note that `izip_longest` returns a generator contains your columns and you can access to items of a generator by `next` method in this case we don't need the first column that is the ids so after calling a `next` then put the result of another `next` method that is the numbers column. and then again apply the `izip_longest` function to that column to get the expected pairs.

Also note that `spamreader` is a csv reader object that returns a generator contains all rows.

Demo :

```
#your file

1 66.295962
2 66.318076
3 66.479436
4 66.460284
5 66.551778
6 66.303606
7 66.222943
8 66.50905
9 66.268011
10 66.291807

#output

0.022114
0.16136
-0.019152
0.091494
-0.248172
-0.080663
0.286107
-0.241039
0.023796
```

Comment: Yes its working , kindly explain the logic behind the program please .. I am  really grateful to you .... :)

Comment: @LifeSciences Welcome! I was doing that! all you need here is a bit knowledge of generators and `zip`.

Comment: but why your answers re showing negative values e.g index 2 - index 1 66.318076 - 66.295962 = 0.022114 but your value is showing negatives, how to correct this ... ??

Comment: @LifeSciences You just need to change the position of `i` and `j`